# Server error 500 at the time of post method

Tags: c#, post, onvif

I am facing problem to make post method from c# 
I got 500 internal server error.

Here is my code which is making call to take time and it include xml document.

I have made same call using ARC plugin, it work fine. But here in .net I am facing problem

```
string Url = "http://10.107.2.153/onvif/device_service";
//System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);// + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data) ? "" : "?" + Data));
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
//req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin","Cisco123");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";//action=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetSystemDateAndTime\"";
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetSystemDateAndTime");
string postData = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl\"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);//Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
try
{
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
    WebResponse errResp = wex.Response;
    using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Exception details please.

Comment: error: 500 Internal Error

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I am able to solve this problem by adding one more parameter as

req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Answer (score 0):

By adding protocolversion parameter issue is resolved.

```
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10
```

it may be issue because of protocol mismatch.